# JSZip read downloaded data (Angular 2)

Tags: json, angular, jszip

I am trying to use JSZip to unzip a JSON file but due to my lack of understanding how JSZip works I get the response in a format that I do not know how to use.

So far this is my code:

```
this.rest.getFile(this.stlLocation).subscribe(
            data => {

                    let JSONFIle = new JSZIP();

                    JSONFIle.file(data.url, data._body, {binary : true, compression : 'DEFLATE'});

                    console.log(JSONFIle);
                },
                err => {
                    this.msgs.push({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error Message', detail: err});
                }
            );
```

So I download a file using an angular 2 service and I use an observable to get the response. When the data is received I finally call JSZip and try to unzip the file but the result of the operation is an intricate object with my data scattered all over the place and buried inside several layers. All I want is the unzipped JSON file that I can open and process.

Thank you for your help,

Dino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a bit of reading I have realized I was going on the wrong path. If you are downloading the file to a browser, you shouldn't have to do anything. Browsers add the Accept-Encoding: 'deflate' header automatically; it is both unnecessary and not good practice to do this at a DOM/JS level. If you are using NGINX the following link may help you out:

[NGINX COMPRESSION AND DECOMPRESSION](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/compression-and-decompression/)